# Filtering a dataframe for specific combinations of variables using a named list

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

I want to filter a nested dataframe for specific combinations of variables using a named list and I can't manage to exclude some unwanted combinations. Here's an example :

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create fake data
set.seed(1234)
data <- tibble(
    c1 = rep(letters[1:3], each = 10),
    c2 = sample(letters[4:6], size = 30, replace = T),
    var1 = rnorm(30),
    var2 = rnorm(30)
)
nested_data <- data %>% 
    nest(.by = c(c1, c2))

# Create list of the specific combinations I want
criteria <- list(a = c("d", "e"), b = "d")
```

I tried to use the functions `names()` and `unique()` to do it but the result does not exclude unwanted combinations with overlapping criterias.

```
# Filter for the specific combinations
c1_criteria <- names(criteria)
c2_criteria <- unique(unlist(criteria))
nested_data %>% 
    filter(c1 %in% c1_criteria,
           c2 %in% c2_criteria) %>% 
    unnest(data)
```

Here's the output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  c1    c2    data            
  <chr> <chr> <list>          
1 a     e     <tibble [5 × 2]>
2 a     d     <tibble [3 × 2]>
3 b     e     <tibble [6 × 2]>
4 b     d     <tibble [1 × 2]>
```

I intended to have only the following combinations : 
`c1 == "a" & c2 == "d"`,
`c1 == "a" & c2 == "e"`,
`c1 == "b" & c2 == "d`"

However, the output also includes the combination, `c1 == "b" & c2 == "e"`. So the intended output is the following :

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  c1    c2    data            
  <chr> <chr> <list>          
1 a     e     <tibble [5 × 2]>
2 a     d     <tibble [3 × 2]>
3 b     d     <tibble [1 × 2]>
```

I think there might be a way to generate a list of specific logical conditions from the named list `criterias` and supply it as argument to the filter function but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could turn that list into a 2-column filtering table that holds desired combinations of c1 & c2, then it can be used with `semi_join()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)
data <- tibble(
  c1 = rep(letters[1:3], each = 10),
  c2 = sample(letters[4:6], size = 30, replace = T),
  var1 = rnorm(30),
  var2 = rnorm(30)
)
nested_data <- data %>% 
  nest(.by = c(c1, c2))

criteria <- list(a = c("d", "e"), b = "d")

enframe(criteria, "c1", "c2") %>% 
  unnest(c2) %>% 
  semi_join(nested_data, .)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(c1, c2)`
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   c1    c2    data            
#>   <chr> <chr> <list>          
#> 1 a     e     <tibble [5 × 2]>
#> 2 a     d     <tibble [3 × 2]>
#> 3 b     d     <tibble [1 × 2]>
```

List transformation steps:

```r
enframe(criteria, name = "c1", value = "c2")
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   c1    c2       
#>   <chr> <list>   
#> 1 a     <chr [2]>
#> 2 b     <chr [1]>

enframe(criteria, "c1", "c2") %>% unnest(c2)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   c1    c2   
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     d    
#> 2 a     e    
#> 3 b     d
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>